Writing to account file
please see my text below. I'm having issues getting it to read from a text file.
Whenever I write to it (by using the signup function as its is encoded) it writes to the file, however it will not allow the script to then read the username and password when trying to login.
Removing the encoding is definitely possible however this is just how i wrote it based off of material ive found around.
This is the error that occurs.
  stored_Username, stored_pwd = f.read().split("\n") ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Any help is greatly appreciated, please keep in mind I am not a programmer or anything this is just for a course I am doing and for some reason coding is apart of it.
import hashlib
import getpass

def signup():
    Username = input("Enter Username: ")
    pwd = input("Enter Password: ")
    conf_pwd = input("Confirm Password: ")

    if conf_pwd == pwd:
        enc = conf_pwd.encode()
        hash1 = hashlib.md5(enc).hexdigest()

        with open("accounts.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(Username + "\n")
            f.write(hash1 + "\n")
        print("You have registered successfully! ")

    else:
        print("Password is not same as above! \n")

def login():
    Username = input("Enter Username: ")
    pwd = input("Enter Password: ")

    auth = pwd.encode()
    auth_hash =hashlib.md5(auth).hexdigest()
    with open("accounts.txt", "r") as f:
        stored_Username, stored_pwd = f.read().split("\n")

    if Username == stored_Username and auth_hash == stored_pwd:
        print("Logged in successfuly!")
    else:
        print("Login failed! \n")

while 1:
    print("********** Login System **********")
    print("1.Signup")
    print("2.Login")
    print("3.Exit")
    ch = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    if ch == 1:
        signup()
    elif ch == 2:
        login()
    elif ch == 3:
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong Choice!")

ENTER=input('Press ENTER to exit')


Havent tried much as i dont know what im doing all that well!

"Haven't tried much": the first step is to debug your code. When you split the contents of the file by "\n", how many values do you expect to get? How many are you expecting to get, when you try to unpack them into stored_Username and stored_pwd?

the issue is that there are multiple lines in the accounts.txt file (which each line has a \n) and you are splitting more than just two lines (which would be stored in stored_Username, stored_pwd) you need to make the split into one variable that would be a list (and then access the even and odd values to get your username and password) and then go through each of those pairs to see if the username and password are already accounts

Your write and read code is not compatible. It wouldn't work with multiple entries anyway. I don't think you interested in details though. Here is an updated version ;)
import hashlib
import getpass
import os

local_account_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + os.sep + "accounts.txt"

def signup():
    Username = input("Enter Username: ")
    pwd = input("Enter Password: ")
    conf_pwd = input("Confirm Password: ")

    if conf_pwd == pwd:
        enc = conf_pwd.encode()
        hash1 = hashlib.md5(enc).hexdigest()


        with open(local_account_file, "a+") as f:
            f.write(Username + ";" + hash1 + "\n")

        print("You have registered successfully! ")

    else:
        print("Password is not same as above! \n")

def login():
    Username = input("Enter Username: ")
    pwd = input("Enter Password: ")

    auth = pwd.encode()
    auth_hash =hashlib.md5(auth).hexdigest()
    with open(local_account_file, "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().split("\n")

        for line in lines:
            stored_credentials = line.strip().split(";")

            if len(stored_credentials) == 2:
                stored_Username = stored_credentials[0]
                stored_pwd = stored_credentials[1]

                if Username == stored_Username and auth_hash == stored_pwd:
                    print("Logged in successfully!")
                    return
    
    print("Login failed! \n")

while 1:
    print("********** Login System **********")
    print("1.Signup")
    print("2.Login")
    print("3.Exit")
    ch = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    if ch == 1:
        signup()
    elif ch == 2:
        login()
    elif ch == 3:
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong Choice!")

ENTER=input('Press ENTER to exit')


Thats exactly how i wanted it to store the credentials aswell, thank you so very much!
